# Skipping Validation for custom fields added to Devise user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I've tried to research this but oddly no one else seems to have this problem or I am not searching right.  Anyway here is my user.rb.  I can create a user no problem and my custom field, 'pin, gets set.  I can  update the 'pin' field.  But if try to change name, email or password they fail because the pin is blank per the validation in my model.  How to skip the pin validation if I am not updating it?  Also, if I update my email, it still sends a confirmation but when I click on the link it validates the pin again and the confirmation fails.  Also, I don't want to regenerate the hash as well in the after_validation helper.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :profiles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :general_settings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :profile_settings, through: :profiles
  has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :videos, through: :profiles
  belongs_to :account_type
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable
  after_validation :create_parent_digest
  validates :pin, presence: true, length:{ is: 4 }, confirmation: true

  attr_accessor :pin, :pin_confirmation

  def valid_pin?(pin)
    Devise::Encryptor.compare(self.class, parent_digest, pin)
  end  

private

    def create_parent_digest
      self.parent_digest = Devise::Encryptor.digest(self.class, pin)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations), you can skip validations on save by adding `validate: false as on option.  For example:

```
@user.save(validate: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use option `on:` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on

For example: 
`validates :pin, presence: true, length:{ is: 4 }, confirmation: true, on: :create`

or you can create a custom context for validation

```
# in model
validates :pin, presence: true, length:{ is: 4 }, confirmation: true, on: :validate_pin

# in controller
@user.save(context: :validate_pin)
```

2. I recommend to do not use callbacks for creating something, just make `create_parent_digest` a public method and call it by hand in controller(or service object)

   ```
   # UsersController
   if @user.save
     @user.create_parent_digest
     ...
   end
   ```

**Edit**: you can do like this

```
# in model
validates :pin, presence: true, length:{ is: 4 }, confirmation: true, on: :validate_pin

# in controller
def create
  @user = User.new params
  if @user.valid?(:validate_pin)
    @user.create_parent_digest
    @user.save
  else
    # do something like render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That will work except it won't validate the pin when I change it. Somehow I need to tell Devise to bypass validation if the pin and pin confirmation fields are blank on the edit page. I notice you can create custom contexts, but they need to be passed to valid? and not_valid? explicitly.

Comment: As for the callback how do I prevent a bare pin being stored in this case, since the Devise controller is saving the record before the pin is hashed?

Comment: I think I might have to create a custom validation method that does all the stuff rails does for me and exit the validation if the pin/pin confirmation is blank and there is a pin digest, then don't add any errors.

Comment: @GHall you need to redefine devise controllers https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers, i edited the answer